# multiple line command and status code

Tags: bash

```
sfdisk -D $val << EOF
,,$type  
EOF
```

How can I check its status after execution? Not via if...$?, but by disjunction ||.
What I mean is I can do the folllowing:
`ls` || exit 4
It will exit with code 4 if ls encountered error, but how can I do it in my example?

And the second question is, how can I perform multiple commands on failure? Is something like this Ok?

```
`ls` || { echo "!!!"; exit 4 }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're actually asking two different questions...

The answer to the first, is that you put the conditions after the << FOO part:

I'm using && here for convience to see the output.  But with this command set:

```
# cat << EOF && ( echo hi ; echo there )
foo
bar
EOF
```

You get:

```
foo
bar
hi
there
```

Answering your second question, you should use ()s:

```
# bash -c 'exit 1' || ( echo hi ; echo there )
hi
there
```

Comment: On the second question: `()` will run its contents in a subshell, which may not be what you want (e.g. exiting, setting variables, etc won't work as you expect).  Instead, use `{}` with a semicolon after the command: `bash -c 'exit 1' || { echo hi; echo there; }`

Comment: Hi. Doesn't work this way:
`sfdisk -D $dev << EOF || { losetup -d $dev ; exit 3 } 
,,$fsys
EOF`

Comment: you need a ';' after the 3 and before the }